# How do I mange to make Unity Color work like pointer?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm drawing a hexagon in Unity using a mesh of six triangles.
The Unity mesh saves the color in the Vertices.
The color is the Unity Engine color.

I want my color to work as a pointer. So that I only change the variable and all the vertices are updated. But it's not working. The Hexagon is white (1f, 1f, 1f) not cyan (0f, 1f, 1f).

I want to use a ponter mechanic for performance reasons.

Please let me know a solution, if you have one. :)

```
        Color devColor = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f);
        meshVertexColor[0] = devColor;
        meshVertexColor[1] = devColor;
        meshVertexColor[2] = devColor;
        meshVertexColor[3] = devColor;
        meshVertexColor[4] = devColor;
        meshVertexColor[5] = devColor;
        meshVertexColor[6] = devColor;
        meshVertexColor[7] = devColor;
        meshVertexColor[8] = devColor;
        meshVertexColor[9] = devColor;
        meshVertexColor[10] = devColor;
        meshVertexColor[11] = devColor;
        meshVertexColor[12] = devColor;
        meshVertexColor[13] = devColor;
        meshVertexColor[14] = devColor;
        meshVertexColor[15] = devColor;
        meshVertexColor[16] = devColor;
        meshVertexColor[17] = devColor;

        devColor.r = 0f;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Color`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html) is a `struct` (**value** type) and not a reference.

When you set

```
meshVertexColor[0] = devColor;
```

it is passed by value so you actually store a **copy** of `devColor`. Any changes afterwards on the local `devColor` value won't automatically update the values in your array/List.

Assuming you are talking about [`Mesh.colors`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-colors.html) you would rather have to do something like

```
public void SetNewColor(Mesh mesh, Color color)
{
    var colors = mesh.colors;
    for(var i = 0; i < colors.Length; i++)
    {
        colors[i] = color;
    }
    mesh.colors = colors;
}
```

so whenever you alter the value of `devColor` you call this method

```
devColor.r = 0;
SetNewColor(theMesh, devColor);
```

---

Could also make it an extension if you want to

```
public static class MeshExtensions
{
    public static void SetNewColor(this Mesh mesh, Color color)
    {
        var colors = mesh.colors;
        for(var i = 0; i < colors.Length; i++)
        {
            colors[i] = color;
        }
        mesh.colors = colors;
    }
}
```

then later you do

```
devColor.r = 0;
theMesh.SetNewColor(devColor);
```